# ifconfig command not working on Kali Linux

Tags: virtual-machine, kali-linux, ifconfig

I installed Kali Linux in a virtual machine, but the `ifconfig` command is not working and permission denied. I've searched many answers on YouTube and Google. But there is no command that works. My PC is 32bit if this helps.

Comment: Were you root when you entered the command?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[`ifconfig`](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/net-tools/ifconfig.8.en.html) is outdated, try [`ip`](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/iproute2/ip.8.en.html) instead. [This meta answer](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me/5361#5361) may also be of relevance.

Comment: I try doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
sudo apt install net-tools
```

and then

```
sudo ifconfig
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the problem in this scenario is an invalid path to commands like `ifconfig` etc.
Firstly, open your Kali Linux terminal and type:

```
nano ./.bashrc
```

For short, this `.bashrc` file is executed every time you open your terminal.
in the very end, paste this:

```
PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
```

This path will lead your terminal to access commands like `ifconfig`.

Point any errors and kindly let me know.